# Canon Pixma MP250 prints only PDF, but not other documents

Tags: printing, pdf, canon, document

I'm using a Canon Pixma MP250 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

The printer is working fine when I need to print a .PDF file, but when I try to print anything else - it only "simulates" printing, but spits out blank pages. 
I tried different applications: LibreOffice, browsers, photo editors - nothing works. Only blank pages are coming out.

Any advice?